# Calling a non-static method in a seperate class to a main program

Tags: java, methods, non-static

I have a Java program where I have a main class and another class called Person (that makes a 'person' class) with 2 methods.  The methods are non-static and are called getName and getAge that stores this info a person element of an ArrayList.
How do I call these in the main program?  I know I have to declare an instance of the class but I'm still not sure how to actually do it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a great resource for very specific questions, but this one sounds like you've basically got a lot to learn - and a very specific answer won't get you terribly far. You'd probably be better reading a good tutorial (e.g. the official one at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/) or a book.

Comment: some code from you would show that you have tried something. This is a trivial question and you may get marked in negative very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

**Considering Person a Class with 2 methods:**

```
 public class Person{

 private String mName;
 private int mAge;

 public Person(String name, String age){

     this.mName = name;
     this.mAge  = age;

  }

 //If you want this class to be Immutable please remove the setter methods()//

 public void setName(String name){

    this.mName = name;


 }

 public void setAge(String age){

    this.mAge = age;


 }


 public String getName(){

    return this.mName ;


 }

 public String getAge(){

    return this.mAge ;


 }

}
```

**The Class containing main() method:**

```
    public class TestMain{

     public static ArrayList<Person> aList = new ArrayList<Person>();


       public static void main(String[] args){


           Person person1 = new Person("Vivek",26);
           Person person2 = new Person("Vicky",27);

           aList.add(person1);
           aList.add(person2);

       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main code you can do something like:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Jericho Jones");
p.setAge(153);
```

Of course, it's impossible to tell exactly without seeing the Person class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate an object for this class.

```
Person p = new Person();
p.getName()....
```